# How to send emails with PHP using the PEAR Mail package with attachment

Tags: php, email, pear, mail-mime

I am trying to send an email with PHP by using the PEAR mail package with an attachment. The email sends successfully with a code I got from the internet. However, the attachment does not get sent or attached. Where am I going wrong, below is my code.

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php"; 
require_once "Mail/mime.php";

$from = "<my.name@company.com>";
$to = "<myname@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Testing email from PHP with attachment";
$body = "Testing email from PHP with attachment";
$file = "invoices/PRINV7_3.pdf";
$host = "host";
$port = "25";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);

$mime = new Mail_mime();

if ($mime->addAttachment($file,'application/pdf')){
    echo "attached successfully! </br>";
} else {
    echo "Nope, failed to attache!! </br>";
}

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }

?>
```

Comment: Where do you add $mime to the mail message?

Comment: That is all I have, if it needs to be added then where should I add it.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't checked this code so if don't work I am sorry

```
include 'Mail.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php';

$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = '/home/richard/example.php';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
    'From' => 'you@yourdomain.com',
    'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
);
$host = "host";
$port = "25";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$mail = & Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
$mail->send('postmaster@localhost', $hdrs, $body);
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works fine. but now I have this warning Warning: Constants may only evaluate to scalar values in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail\mime.php on line 1089

Comment: You can suppress with @ check line by line see where the warning is throwing.

Comment: This doesn't explain where the author is wrong, so it doesn't answer the question. This is just sharing working code.  However, the code is easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add the headers from your `$mime` object to your `$headers`

```
$attachmentheaders = $mime->headers($headers);
```

and then change your mail call:

```
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $attachmentheaders, $body);
```

Here's a tutorial that may help:
http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'Mail.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php' ;
$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '
<html>
<body>HTML version of email</body>
</html>
';
$file = '/home/richard/example.php';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
'From'    => 'you@yourdomain.com',
'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
 );
$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');
$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);
$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send('postmaster@localhost', $hdrs, $body);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working code from one of my apps:

```
/**
  *  
  * @param type $recipient
  * @param type $subject
  * @param type $message
  * @param type $attachment
  *  
  * To make this mail PEAR work, I needed to do:
  * pear install mail
  * pear install Net_SMTP
  * pear install Mail_Mime
  * 
*/

public function sendmail($recipient, $subject, $message, $attachment = '') {
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";
$from = "Dispatcher <server@mymailserver.com>";
$host = "smtp.mymailserver.com";
$port = "587";
$username = "mailuser";
$password = "password";

$headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $recipient, 'Subject' => $subject);

if ($attachment != '') {
  $crlf = "\n";
  $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
  $mime->setTXTBody($message);
  $mime->addAttachment($attachment, 'application/pdf');
  $body = $mime->get();
  $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
} else {
  $body = $message;
}

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$smtp->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain where the author is wrong, so it doesn't answer the question.  This is just sharing working code.  Even with that aside, the code is difficult to read.